# how to redirect folders browsing to error 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using wordpress and have some folders that users shouldn't see and browse. For this found solution - adding this line in .htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes or Options -Indexes
```

But it redirects to 403 - FORBIDDEN page of server, I need to redirect to my site's error 404 page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root wordpress you can do this:

```
# handles 403 (forbidden) status as 404 (not found)
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?error=404

# disables directory listing
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thanks much. @anubhava

Comment: @anubhava can you look into this please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002549/options-indexes-not-redirecting-to-404-error-page-wordpress

Answer (score 2):

You could create an index.php in those directories with following code:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
die('Page not found');
```

Comment: I have created index.php and code that you wrote but it redirects me to ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR page @Raja Amer Khan

Comment: The code is fine, I think you have some wrong configuration in your .htaccess file. Comment out rules for htaccess and then check.

Comment: Here is my htaccess # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
Redirect 404 /folder-name/ @Raja Amer Khan

Comment: please refer to this guide for your solution: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Answer (score 2):

You can try with specific folder name like

Redirect 404 /folder1/

Redirect 404 /folder2/

Comment: I have done in this way now it redirects to server's 404 page, I need to redirect my site's 404 page @HEMANT SUMAN

Comment: You need to create custom 404 page add this line 

ErrorDocument 404 /custom_page.html

Comment: 1. You cannot have more than 1 404 handlers in .htaccess 2. This solution has no bearing on 403

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your .htaccess file which is in root of your website.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /file_not_found.html
```

And `file_not_found.html` should be in root folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
DirectoryIndex /404.php
```

Comment: Same problem it redirects to server's 404 page, I need to redirect to my 404 page @Starkeen

Comment: It indeed redirects to your 404 page, do you have a /404.php file?

Comment: @aidaghazaryan: You need to replace `/404.php` with the path to your 404-page, of course. And that 404-page should also make sure (via script) that the HTTP status code it returns is `404`, no matter how it is executed. Otherwise this would result in a `HTTP 200 OK` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution by just adding index.html file in those folders, and nothing in .htaccess file. Thanks everyone